# How to make this canvas effect, moving on the background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

In this site: http://shape.themeturn.com/html/dhome/index.html you can see there is a Dot line effect which moves with the mouse. You will find it in the header section.

I wanna know what are those effects called. I think they created it with HTML5 canvas (i, might be wrong!). How can i create such effect. And what skills are required??

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Is that build with jQuery and Canvas??

Comment: Ya thanks! Can you give me some kind reference, where i can start learning to create that kind of effect.

Comment: No idea of your javascript skill level, so, pretty hard to know what to recommend

Answer (score 0):

**Here's an outline to get you started.**

1. Cover a desired part of the window with a canvas element,
2. Clear the canvas,
3. When the mouse moves find the mouse position,
4. Calculate many random point coordinates on the canvas within a desired radius of the mouse,
5. Connect (with a line) each point in #4 with it's nearest 5 neighboring points,
6. Emphasize each point in #4 by drawing a small circle around those points,
7. Wait a small bit of time and repeat starting at step#2.